# Where the layout reads the resources?

Tags: android, resources, android-layout, overriding

Which method i must override, that the `xml layout` use to read the `resources` linked with, sample:

if i had `TextView` within my `layout`:

```
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:text="@String/text_test1"
                </TextView>
```

and in my `Activity` in `onCreate`, we always use `setContentView`:
`setContentView(R.layout.sample);`

--

my question is : when we use **xml** file as layout in activities, how the layout reads the resources like `android:text="@String/text_test1`, so i can for example override it, so when the layout request any `String` i can bind another text to it ?

--

**Note** : am not looking for regular way, by finding the view in the XML, and then change it properties.
am looking for `abstract` way to change every `String` requested in the `resources` by xml layout.

Comment: why would you need to override this functionality? simply use 

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1)).setText("blah")

Comment: @herbert sorry, i dont need that way, am making `Abstract Activity`, so every `Resource` request, i must handle something in all `Strings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the text you need to simply use this in your activity.

```
  ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1)).setText("New Text");
```

To override the entire TextView you need to create a custom textview class that extends TextView and perform your stuff there.

Comment: sorry, i dont need that way, am making `Abstract Activity`, so every `Resource` request, i must handle something in all `Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the text by code use this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.yourtextishere));

Comment: sorry, i dont need that way, am making `Abstract Activity`, so every `Resource` request, i must handle something in all `Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you mean exatly.
Anyway in the `res/` folder there are all the resources that your application will need at runtime. A String is a resource defined in the `value/string.xml` file.

At complie time the ADT generate a java static class that bind an ID for any of your resources, strings too. So when you set the layout of your activity the vaule of the string will be get by the specific ID in that class.

if you ment to change the textView text you'll just have to get the object rappresenting the textView at runtime with:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

and the use his methods to set the text:

```
textView.setText("New Text");
```

hope this will help.